# Ubuntu source package dependency tree

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I have some packages. Let's call them `A.deb`, `B.deb` and `C.deb`. Each package has a corresponding source package `A.dsc` and `A.tar.gz`, `B.dsc` and `B.tar.gz`, `C.dsc` and `C.tar.gz`. The packages depend on each other: `C.deb` depends on `B.deb` and `B.deb` depends on `A.deb`

If I modify `A.deb`, I need to rebuild `B.deb` or it won't work. The same goes for `B.deb` and `C.deb`. Is there a way to automate this process? Is there perhaps a tool or script that will do it for me? If not, how could I automate it myself?

In addition, There are not my packages.

Comment: You're saying "C.deb depends on B.deb and B.deb depends on A.deb", so I guess you're referring to *binary* packages? Also are you referring to the compilation of B against an external library in A? If so there simply *shouldn't* be the need to rebuild the package, given that the developer(s) of A didn't change such library's interface (so this is up to A's mantainer(s), not to B's mantainer(s); if you are the developer of all of them then just simply keep the implementation of A agnostic from its interface the most as possible, so that compatibility in ensured at its most).

Comment: I was looking for such sometime ago, but i get nothing. So if such thing was available, they would use it for PPA. Even with ppa's, daily build is auto run only on source code update only. I couldn't get a ref about Ubuntu, but Debian has something called AutoBuild that it builds only new uploads (them-self, not their dependents) to multiple arch. It seem like things still manual. A/maintainer should not make major upgrades on same release, C/maintainer keep watch the uploads mailing list or the package tracker.

Comment: I think that idea will take much resources if it was implemented. On new upload of gcc or libc, that system will have to rebuild almost all packages (kind of chain-reaction)

Comment: I don't do stuff at this level on Linux, but I think that was what `make` was invented for. A makefile includes rules which determine what needs to be recompiled/rebuilt based on what has changed.

Comment: @Sneetsher yes, I think so but, although it takes much resources, I want to do it.

Comment: @Joe make is just works in a source package, coult not work outside.

Comment: I don't know `make`much at all, but I was under the impression that you could define make rules to do just about anything - not just run a compile. I'll bet rules could be configured to build a deb or just about anything else - if one knew how.

Comment: I think that It can be implemented by make's functions. Makefile's sub goals will be binary packages, conditions will be source packages and binary packages. Command line will be pbuilder or dpkg-buildpackage, debuild ... It's possible?

Comment: @xiaodongjie - you are a dear person with a dear question - so you know bash already and bash-scripting ? ---> this way you could write a little script with switch-case loop and then like in an elevator build into different cases what to do about the packages. There is not my script. You are brainy like we are brainy - do laugh. - this script can of course can be set up like a daemon (to work automatically).

Comment: A @Joe said: use `make`, and as you said yourself, @xiaodongjie, the make targets would be the resulting packages, with their package-to-package dependencies declared, and the associated action for each target would be the command that makes the package. Install `make-doc` and type `info make` to read all about it.

Comment: What about creating an alias for the build process?

Comment: Perhaps it's possible and best way i think. And i wonder how can i create the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a Makefile with the build dependencies declared, for example as follows:

```
default: A.deb B.deb C.deb

C.deb: B.deb C.dsc C.tar.gz
        <command(s) to build C.deb>

B.deb: A.deb B.dsc B.tar.gz
        <command(s) to build B.deb>

A.deb: A.dsc A.tar.gz
        <command(s) to build A.deb>
```

*Note that the command indentation is a TAB.*

With that `Makefile`, you would use the command

```
make
```

and this would work out which packages to build and in which order, and then build them, all depending on the timestamps of the files. E.g., if say `B.tar.gz` has a timestamp later than `B.deb` (i.e. package `B` has new source), then that'd cause firstly `B.deb` to be rebuilt, and as that would make it be stamped later than `C.deb`, it would cause `C.deb` to be rebuilt as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe I'm totally missing your point, but it sounds like you're recompiling package A and want to recompile packages B & C, wich I would simply us a [makefile](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make) for.

Comment: Can you explain more detail?

Comment: or any example.